# Days colors in Wordpress calendar

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fullcalendar

I am working on a wordpress project in which I need to display a calendar with specific day colors: Saturdays are yellow, Mondays are blue and so on... I tried using the FullCalendar plugin but it didn't work, here's an example:

```
    .fc-sat, .fc-sun{
background-color: yellow;
}
```

any ideas on how to change it or if there is another plugin that would do the job?

Comment: where you place css?

Comment: i placed it in the fullcalendar.css file

Comment: Try to ad !important afrer yellow

Comment: still doesn't work :/

Comment: It's possibile display url of calendar?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You have a public url where calendar is placed?

Comment: oh no i don't !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `eventAfterRender` in the initialization of the calendar as follows:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view) {

   if (event.start.day() == 0) {
            element.css('background-color', 'blue');
            element.css('border-color', 'blue'); // colors first day of the week blue
   }
  else if (event.start.day() == 1) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you! i had to change it a little though because i'm not taking events into consideration. Here is how i changed:                 if (date.day() == 0) {
            cell.css('background-color', 'blue');
            cell.css('border-color', 'blue'); // colors first day of the week blue
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you theme css:

```
.fc-sat{ background: yellow !important; }
```